# Couldn't able to find plugins in ThingsBoard 2.0.3 Home screen

Tags: thingsboard

Installed ThingsBoard 2.0.3 on Ubuntu 18.04. Logged in on tenant account but still couldn't able to find plugins in ThingsBoard Home screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved !**
Plugins are replaced with Rule Engine nodes now on the ThingsBoard 2.0.3.