# How to connect Kafka to Thingsboard Platform

Tags: apache-kafka, thingsboard

I want to activate the Kafka Spark pipeline for the Thingsboard platform (community edition).

As per the mentioned Stack question "[Couldn't able to find plugins in ThingsBoard 2.0.3 Home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386576/couldnt-able-to-find-plugins-in-thingsboard-2-0-3-home-screen)"

It's been said that we can do it via Rule chains itself since the plugin section has been removed, but I am not able to understand how to configure it using rule chains. I am not able to get the complete documentation to configure Kafka via rule chains. So need help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. By using this link it can be done easily "https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/analytics/kafka-streams/"

The thing is that using the Thingsboard CE we can get data into Kafka-topic. However, to fetch data from Kafka you will need to have TB Professional Edition integration.
The alternate option to Thingsboard PE is to write your own REST API script to push the insights back to ThingsBoard.